# Spring Scheduled Job to skip based on certain time range

Tags: java, spring, cron

I currently have a spring scheduled job as below which needs to run based on cron expression and it works fine as expected.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * * *")
public void myJob() {
   //actions
}
```

**Question:**

Now I want to include a check if the cron job runs during a predetermined and configurable time period. If yes, skip the processing.. For example, I want the main cron job to be skipped for 1 hour, between Sunday 8:30AM to 9:30AM.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * * *")
public void myJob() {
   if(current time is sunday 8.30AM to 9.30AM){
      return;
   }
}
```

My thought was to use 2 cron expression to denote start and end values. But not sure how to implement the verification.

```
private String startCronExpression = "0 30 8 * * 7";
private String endCronExpression = "0 30 9 * * 7";
```

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To run the job all days but not in a specific time, it is possible to write the range of hours wanted :
Example : `@Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 0-7,9-0 * * *")`

Comment: I am afraid this can't be used for time period like 7.40 to 8.40am.

Comment: this won't work starting just from 8 to 9.

Comment: As commented, it does not give flexibility on Time

Answer (score 0):

Cron expression supports lists, so you can just try this:

```
0 */10 0-7,9-23 * * *
```

Comment: I am afraid this can't be used for time period like 7.40 to 8.40am.