# How to schedule cron job in spring boot to run for every 5 minutes with in specific period

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron

I have the following code in spring boot, its working fine and job running for every 5 mins.

I want it run between 9:30 AM to 5:30 PM for every 5 minutes.

How to add the the specific time period for below cron expression.

`@Scheduled(cron = “0 */5 * ? * *”)`

`public void runEvey5Minutes() {`

`System.out.println(“Current time is :: “ + LocalDate.now());`

`}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Scheduled Job to skip based on certain time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516612/spring-scheduled-job-to-skip-based-on-certain-time-range)

Comment: @Chin Huang - it doesnt answer my question completely as my requirement is start job from 9 hours and 30 mins AM and job should run for every 5 mins till 5 Hours 30 minutes PM

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do it in one expression, but I doubt it.
The hard part is that is starts at 8:30 AM and end at 5:30 PM. So the interval is not symetric, I thinks this make it impossible to parse into one expression.

My idea would be to split it in 3 expression:

```
- 8:30 - 8:55
 = 0 30/5 8 * ? *

- 9:00AM - 4:59PM  
 = 0 0/5 9-16 * ? *

- 5:00PM - 5:30PM  
 = 0 0-30/5 17 * * ?
```

Then you would need 3 methods with the `@Scheduled` annotation, they should al run the same job of course.

If you want to test if they work, check out this [code](https://gist.github.com/JonasGroeger/4c73439059fdc629977bf58ed0fd17a5)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

#### As @Gijs Den Hollander Said,

To run every 5 minutes but only between 8:30 AM and 5:30 PM, you can't achieve this with a single cron expression within Spring Boot's configuration. Cron itself doesn't have a built-in way to specify a time range within an hour.

We need to break it into three cron jobs. Itinvolves creating three separate cron entries in your Spring Boot configuration:

One for every 5 minutes between 9:30 AM and 9:55 AM.
Another for every 5 minutes between 9:00 AM and 5:00 PM.
A third entry for every 5 minutes between 5:00 PM and 5:30 PM.

```py
0 30/5 9 * * *  # Run every 5 minutes between 9:30 AM and 9:55 AM
0 0/5 10-16 * * *  # Run every 5 minutes between 9:00 AM and 5:00 PM
0 0-30/5 17 * * *  # Run every 5 minutes between 5:00 PM and 5:30 PM
```

#### Alternatively You can do

or else you can do below.
You can add a condition to check when the scheduler started

```
@Scheduled(cron = “0 */5 9-15 * * *”)

public void runEvey5Minutes() {

//check the time it falls within your time frame and execute your code
if(condition){
}
}
```

Comment: You just copied my answer?

Comment: I want to clarify that my intention was not to imply that I copied your answer. Instead, I merely suggested the inclusion of an 'if' condition in the code to enhance its effectiveness. Upon reflection, I realize that a portion of my response coincided with yours. I genuinely appreciate your contribution and I regret not acknowledging it initially. Please accept my apologies for this oversight.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and edit. I guess you do elaborate, so it might help OP.